# Sql Select Statment in Access VB returning the incorrect values

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, vba

I have written the following code in Access VB:

```
strSqlPay = "select * from T_Payment " & _
             "where StudentID = " & Me.ID.value & _
             "  And SchoolYear = """ & Year.value & """"
Set recSetPay = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSqlPay)
countpay = recSetPay.RecordCount
```

The `T_Payment` table contains the following information:

```
ID  StudentID  SchoolYear  Semester  PaymentType  CheckNumber  AmountDue  AmountPaid  DatePaid

4   468        13          Fall      Check        100          $130.00    $130.00     29-Jul-16
5   468        13          Spring    Check        101           $60.00      $60.00      29-Jul-16
9   468        14          Fall      Check                     $190.00     $190.00      29-Jul-16
11    1        12          Fall      Cash           0            $1.00       $1.00      07-Mar-16
```

A form triggers the code and gives the StudentID = 468 and SchoolYear = 14.  The count returns 3 records. not what I am looking for.  if I take the same statement and run it in a query I get what I am looking for which is 1 record.

I also need to figure out how to expand my select statement to include Semester = "Fall" but I can not figure out how to add this and make it work.

I hope I have given enough information for someone to help me.

Please can anyone help me,  Thank you!

Comment: Is that table correct?  The third row of data has one less field than the other rows.

Comment: yes it does not have a check number filled in

Answer (score 0):

```
strSqlPay = "SELECT Count(*) AS RecCnt " & _
            "  FROM T_Payment " & _
            " WHERE StudentID = " & Me.ID.Value & _
            "   AND Val(SchoolYear) = " & Me.Year.Value & _
            "   AND UCase(Semester) = ""FALL"""
Set recSetPay = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSqlPay)
countpay = recSetPay.Fields("RecCnt").Value
```

This assumes that SchoolYear is alpha and Me.Semester has "Fall" or "Spring" in it. Also, I haven't actually run this code, so it might have a typo in it.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work but I am running into issues.  SchoolYear is a string value and Semester is just text and not a value from the form.  this section is run just for the fall semester and I was going to hard code this and just have it look up the word "Fall"

Comment: I modified it to look only for "Fall"

Comment: that worked.  thank you so much.  I am still confused why I would get different values in the vb code vs running in a query.  any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure. I don't put much faith in the DAO RecordSet's RecordCount property. I suspect that's where the problem was. You shouldn't get MORE  rows by adding an `AND` to a SQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You'll get the same number using Recordcount - but you need to move the end of the recordset first to get it - then go back to first record when you want to start processing. 'recSetPay.MoveLast` then `countpay = recSetPay.RecordCount` then `countpay = recSetPay.MoveFirst`

Answer (score 0):

You get the ID value using `Me.ID.value`, but the year value with `Year.Value` rather than `Me.Year.Value`.  Not 100% sure, but this could return the incorrect records - it may just be looking at ID = 468 and ignoring year?

As @StoneGiant said - is `Year` a text field or numeric field as you're treating it as text.  Would be easier to use a `'` rather than a `"` to wrap your text though.
e.g. `SchoolYear = '" & Year.value & "'`

Comment: Thanks I tried that too and it still returns 3 records.

Comment: if I just have this strSqlPay = "select * from T_Payment where SchoolYear = '" & Me.Year.value & "'  I get just one record

Comment: but when I add strSqlPay = "select * from T_Payment where SchoolYear = '" & Me.Year.value & "'" & " And StudentID = " & me.ID.value
I get 3 records again

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement isn't filtering for just the last record. That's why you're getting 3 records. You'll have to have some way to keep track of the order these records were entered and then pick off just that record. So something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM T_Payment 
WHERE StudentID = Me.ID.value
    AND SchoolYear = Year.value
    AND Semester = 'Fall'
ORDER BY ID DESC
```